# Python Numpy array creation from multiple lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning more about numpy and need help creating an numpy array from multiple lists. Say I have 3 lists,

```
a = [1, 1, 1] 
b = [2, 2, 2] 
c = [3, 3, 3]
```

How can I create a new numpy array with each list as a column? Meaning that the new array would be `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`. I know how to do this by looping through the lists but I am not sure if there is an easier way to accomplish this. The numpy concatenate function seems to be close but I couldn't figure out how to get it to do what I'm after.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with `np.column_stack`:

```
d = np.column_stack([a, b, c])
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `numpy`.  Python `zip` does a nice job:

```
In [606]: a = [1, 1, 1] 
     ...: b = [2, 2, 2] 
     ...: c = [3, 3, 3] 
In [607]: abc = list(zip(a,b,c))
In [608]: abc
Out[608]: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

But if your heart is set on using `numpy`, a good way is to make a 2d array, and transpose it:

```
In [609]: np.array((a,b,c))
Out[609]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
In [610]: np.array((a,b,c)).T
Out[610]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Others show how to do this with `stack` and `column_stack`, but underlying these is a `concatenate`.  In one way or other they turn the lists into 2d arrays that can be joined on axis=1, e.g.

```
In [616]: np.concatenate([np.array(x)[:,None] for x in [a,b,c]], axis=1)
Out[616]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Why double parenth?

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111, it could also be `np.array([a,b,c])`

Comment: Oh gotcha. Thanks for a quick reply!